# Error: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const 11111" to "bytes32"

Tags: solidity

I have the following code snippet:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
  contract Puzzle {
     address payable public owner ;
     bool public locked ;
     uint public reward ;
     bytes32 public diff ;
     bytes public solution ;


    constructor () public {
       owner = msg.sender ;
       reward = msg.value ;
       locked = false ;
       diff = bytes32 (11111); // pre - defined difficulty
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> > solc Puzzle_sha256.sol Puzzle_sha256.sol:14:12: Error: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const 11111" to "bytes32".
> >         diff = bytes32 (11111); // pre - defined difficulty
> >                ^-------------^

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: Why do you need to convert a `number` to `string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, convert `int_const` to `uint256` then convert it to `bytes32`.

```
diff = bytes32 (uint256(11111));
```

and there is another problem with your contract.

You are using `msg.sender` and `msg.value` in your `constructor`. For that you need to mark your `constructor` as `payable`.

```
constructor() payable public
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also convert `int_const` to `uint256` using OpenZeppelin's SafeCast library and then convert to `bytes32`

```
diff = bytes32(SafeCast.toUint256(11111));
```

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/utils#SafeCast